# Firebase как сделать сортировку по свежей записи?

Tags: firebase

Помогите пожалуйста ,использую Firebase,мне нужно чтобы новые записи появлялись сверху списка,как создать запрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам нужно использовать при получение данных `"child_added"` он слушает кто был добавлен при этом вы можете добавить `.limit(5)` надеюсь  названия слова говорит за себя . все это выведет 5 последних запесей . и еще вы можете воспользоваться equalTo() дочерние значение будет равно чему будет указано

```
ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("david").limit(5).on("child_added", function(snapshot)
```

в вашам случие можна использовать число

```
 ref.orderByChild("date").equalTo("12/8/2016").limit(5).on("child_added", function(snapshot)
```